# How to effectively use the self-documenting system of Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I am a newbie on Emacs. I was going to learn how to close a buffer, so I typed `M-x` `apropos-documentation RET`  `close buffer`. Then I got a lot of useless information.

Given the above senario, what's the right way to find what I wanna know using the self-documenting system?

Or the self-documenting system is useless compared to Google in the modern day?

Comment: It's not useless, it's just that emacs uses a different terminology: you don't close buffers but *kill* them. Anyway, it could certainly be improved, by listing synonyms and such. You can help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are better off with Google until you know the terminology and maybe even after that. I've used the emacs documentation system a lot, but mainly for looking up something which I already knew about, or something for which I already knew the exact terminology.

If you are unsure how to search for something in the documentation then Google is much more effective, because it also takes synoyms into account and it finds questions similar to yours from forums and stuff. It does not only apply to Emacs, but to any other software as well. Regardless of the software I always try a Google search first, because in most cases Google throws out the answer much more quickly than browsing the documentation,

Comment: If you *ask Emacs* you will get answers which are correct for the version of Emacs that you happen to be using.  If you search on the web you may also get answers which are for older or newer versions of Emacs, and do not apply to your version.  Sometimes web searches are extremely useful, and will turn up information that you won't find in the manual; but I think it's terrible that the question "How to effectively use the self-documenting system of Emacs?" has an accepted answer which steers you away from that documentation.

Answer (score 6):

When you are just beginning with Emacs, the best documentation to start with is the tutorial. You can get there with `C-h t`. A half hour spent doing the tutorial will show you all the basics, including buffer management. This will save you a lot of time compared to searching for each command individually, either via Google or apropos.

Another benefit of the tutorial is that you'll get a quick overview of Emacs' idiosyncratic terminology. For example, the word 'kill' is used as a near-synonym for 'delete'. Searching for 'kill buffer' with apropos would likely have answered your question.

Answer (score 4):

So a basic terminology problem tripped you up here. I would say that Emacs doesn't help here by not catering for this case in the glossary, and naming the relevant menu item "Close" and binding it to a different function to the <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> sequence (which would be to avoid prompting you again). I note that the tooltip for that menu item does at least indicate the "kill" terminology, however, which certainly would have assisted your search.

That mismatch was always going to cause problems for searching with `apropos`, but the self-documentation in Emacs goes beyond that. Really, the tutorial or user manual should have been your next step. (The tutorial should be your *first* step, in fact.)

Any of the following would have found you the answer fairly quickly, even without knowing the "kill" term.

- Go through the tutorial: <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>
- Look for "buffer" in the manual's contents page: <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>
- Search the manual's index <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> `buffers` <kbd>RET</kbd>
  (admittedly searching for `buffer` (singular) provides more cluttered results)
- Search the keybindings: <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>M-x</kbd> `occur` <kbd>RET</kbd> `buffer` <kbd>RET</kbd>
  (`occur` is a bit more advanced, but <kbd>C-s</kbd> would work too)
- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> *click the "File" -> "Close" menu item*
  (which is not the same binding as <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> as commented on above; but this would also have shown the "kill" terminology)

I think it's a bit of a shame that the accepted answer for a question entitled "How to effectively use the self-documenting system of Emacs?" is one which steers you away from those systems, as once you know your way around them you'll rarely need anything *other* than Emacs' own documentation.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, just because you did not understand the information, it does not mean that it is useless.

Second of all, once you have even the slightest idea what commands are called, you can do `M-x`, and tab-expand the command. Once you've invoked it, emacs will also flash up a message telling you the key binding for that command if there is one.

Answer (score 3):

Get aquainted with th `C-h` chords [[1]](http://www.math.uh.edu/~bgb/emacs_keys.html):

```
C-h a        command-apropos      What commands work like this...?
C-h c        describe-key-briefly What command does this key sequence do?
C-h b        describe-bindings    What are the key bindings for this buffer?
C-h k        describe-key         What command does this sequence do?
C-h l        view-lossage         What are the last 100 characters typed?
C-h w        where-is             What is the key binding for this?
C-h f        describe-function    What does this function do?
C-h v        describe-variable    What is this variable?
C-h o        describe-symbol      What is this symbol? (function, variable or face)
C-h m        describe-mode        Tell me about this mode.
C-h s        describe-syntax      What is the syntax table for this buffer?
```

Although they wouldn't have helped with the particular query you were after, they come in handy very often.  As for `apropos`, give up.  Use Google and the Emacs Wiki instead.

Comment: @phils More useful than the web?  Not a chance.  Apropos (as with most built-in program help systems) is a legacy of the days before  permanent web access and search engines.

Comment: Unlike the web, `apropos` is always correct for the version of Emacs you are using. Call it a legacy if you will, but it remains a vital part of the Emacs documentation. I'm not questioning the usefulness of search engines on the web, but if you can find a web site which reliably returns you the list of variables in your running Emacs instance with values matching a given regexp, I'll be *mightily* impressed (and not a little concerned). The `apropos` commands are tools which perform their specific purpose better than anything else.

Comment: Sure, if that's what you really want then apropos may be best.  But most of the time you just want to know how to do something, not what variables happens to match a regexp.  For answering a natural language question, the web is still unbeatable.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an extensive tutorial on learning Emacs via its built-in help and elisp source code: http://david.rothlis.net/emacs/howtolearn.html

Several people have found it very useful.

The self-documenting nature of Emacs is *amazing* (once you learn your way around).

Answer (score 3):

Also

```
 emacs-index-search
 elisp-index-search
```